# Divine temporality and spacetime

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-religion, time

[According](https://www.iep.utm.edu/god-time/) to the IEP,

> The majority position today, at least among philosophers, is that God is everlasting but temporal.

How is the idea of divine temporality reconciled with special relativity? Special relativity [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) that space and time are deeply intertwined; one cannot exist without the other. How, then, can we have a presumably non-spatial God exist within time? It seems that special relativity requires God to exist within space to be temporal, but I assume that most philosophers reject this.

Comment: The majority position is based on what is called [presentism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presentism/#RelaPhys), which is explicitly at odds with the prevailing interpretation of special (and general) relativity by physicists. Presentists do offer alternative interpretations of relativity that supply absolute time (e.g. Lorentz's theory of ether). Alternatively, one can adopt an eternalist position where God experiences what is called "duration", a timeless version of "temporality", see [SEP Views on God and Time](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/eternity/#SomeViewGodTime).

Comment: FWIW: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1302/1302.2603.pdf : "If one endorsers a scientifically informed philosophy of time, it turns out, contrary to conventional wisdom, that presentism does not have to be seen at odds with the relativity of simultaneity."

Comment: @Conifold I can't say I can grasp what exactly "duration" means here. Can duration be measured on a clock? Does our world have time and duration, just time, or something else?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thank you, that's an interesting read!

Comment: Certainly not. It is experiential, and does not mix with the physical  concepts. Moreover, it is something other than our experience of succession, since "*eternity […] is the whole, simultaneous, and perfect possession of boundless life*", as Boethius said. God's "eternal present" is sometimes compared to our experience of [specious present](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time-experience/#SpecPres), which is not instantaneous and has extension, i.e. "endures", only encompassing the whole of time (or spacetime). There are still difficulties with relativity that durationists try to address.

Comment: @Conifold I suppose that there is some meaning there, but it still seems somewhat nebulous to me. On another note, when presentists try to mesh their views on time with relativity, is it the sort of explanation which can be empirically proven correct or incorrect, or is it one which cannot be (which I think is the status with quantum mechanics, where no interpretation can really be proven).

Comment: Shouldn't nebulousness be expected when it comes to the Divine :) Theists readily admit that God is really transcendent to the world with its physics, and beyond human comprehension, all we can have are imperfect analogies. The transcendent and the empirical are "non-overlapping magisteria", and never the twain shall meet, so no, theology is not subject to empirical testing. The more mundane and specific versions of presentism, like Lorentz's theory, can, in principle, be verified, e.g. if we finally found a way to detect ether. But even if it were falsified I am sure it can be "amended".

Comment: @Conifold I wonder if it's possible to have an atemporal God without invoking modern physics. If we assume an "absolute" time, in which case everything presumably has a "timestamp," if you will, then God must also (?). Why, then, did many thinkers before relativity was established think that God could exist outside of time?

Comment: Absolute space and time stamps are a creation of mechanistic physics, mostly Newton's. Aristotle's, [Leibniz's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#6), and Kant's theories were relational, space and time were interpreted as our projections to organize interactions. Modern "time is emergent" theories are similar in spirit, the [Hartle-Hawking proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartle%E2%80%93Hawking_state) even reminds me the neo-Platonic and Christian speculations about an atemporal entity giving rise to the temporal world.

Comment: @Conifold If one says that space is needed for time, what is of substance dualism, then? Many theists also accept substance dualism, yet if time cannot exist for anything not in space, then how can the mind experience time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have omitted the modality and are misrepresenting the quote. They are guessing that this *may be* the majority position.

Also, if you read the next sentence, there is not a conflict between that and relativity. Non-locality just requires God would have to be everywhere in space as well as everywhere in time.  But why is that a problem?

It is already something most monotheists have assumed. After all, most of them assume prayer is immediately received by Him wherever it originates. We have churches, but not temples to which you need access to reach specific aspects of God.

If God is everywhere, then the nonlocality of quantum mechanics, and he interconnectedness of spacetime insist he automatically has to be present at all times.  So an immanent God is temporal and perpetual one, 'aeternal' (one present for all time) but not 'eternal' one (outside time).

Comment: A few sentences after that, they say, "That is, God experiences some events (for example, the first century) before he experiences other events (for example, the twenty-first century.)" If I'm not mistaken, this is *explicitly* rejected by the popular interpretation of relativity. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-theory_of_time#B-theory_in_theoretical_physics), "The B-theory of time has received support from the physics community.[17][18] This is likely due to its compatibility with physics and the fact that many theories such as special relativity..."

Comment: @user40443 Don't *you* experience some events before other events?  Isn't our sense of time locally linear?  If relativity doesn't prevent you from having this experience, why would it rule out God's having it?  The B-theory of time is not really about individual experience, it is about succession as a whole.  For time to be an illusion, it has to be an experience first.  There is nothing preventing God from participating in that experience, knowing it is artificial, even if it comes down to the C.S. Lewis notion of having some version of all experiences in order to better judge mortals.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. This is a tangentially related question, but do you know of any sources where the effects of relativity are discussed on dualism? It seems that an additional assumption is needed to say that an immaterial soul can experience the material world like this (in a temporal fashion).

Comment: @user40443 Again, if you accept some form of dualism do you presume your immaterial soul cannot experience the material world?  If so, what is the point of your dualism?  I don't have a reference, but I don't think dualism itself is compatible with 'information' as an aspect of physics, which is a component of both relativity and quantum theory now.  But other perspectives on God, like pan(hen)theism work.  The related question becomes 'What is experience for a being who already knows everything? Shouldn't experience change the content of memory?'  You get the rock lifting problem again.

Comment: The point of departure is that *an immanent God* is also not a dualist one.  An immaterial God is not logically everywhere, but nowhere.  But that makes miracles hard to deal with.  The dualist notion of God is tied up a lot with the mechanical notion of physics.  We are officially past the latter, we just can't really fathom that yet.

Comment: 1) What exactly do you mean by saying that 'information' in the physics sense is incompatible with dualism? 2) Why can miracles not occur in a quantum, as opposed to mechanical, world? 3) Thank you for your insights, they're certainty interesting, but my question was more for dualism for us, humans, not God.

Comment: To clarify my 3rd question, I'm not talking about a dualist notion of God (even though it's not fully clear in my mind how that is incompatible with modern physics), I'm talking about dualism in the sense that us humans are dualistic - our minds are a non-physical substance.

Comment: 2) I am saying the opposite. Miracles in a quantum world just are not violations of the physics, right?  They necessary randomness means they are unlikely, but not forbidden.  They do not call for an agent, then, and we do not have to put God outside reality.  1) We also have modern relativity, which binds together space and time, energy and information.  That means that 'experiencing' is no longer some mystical thing outside physics.  It is some use of information, which is now *inside* physics.  The boundaries needed for dualism have been rendered into continuous spaces and not bright lines.

Comment: 3) There are not two different things here.  Dualism stays or goes, whether you apply it to God, or the 'shared mind', or individual minds.  And I don't see how you can both measure the flow of information within physics and assume that one of its main repositories lies outside physics.  You open up the door to a bigger and more mandatory version of Maxwell's Demon.

Comment: At this point, this has gone on too long...  I am violating the agenda of the forum, which is to get competing perspectives.  It might makse sense to try to formulate a new question that would get others to question my perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I would want some evidence that the majority of philosophers place God in time eternally. The idea makes no sense. It places limits on what is defined as limitless and requires a fundamental space-time. I would have thought the majority of philosophers either reject the idea of God or assume He is fundamental and prior to space-time.

I would hope that the majority of philosophers have a more sophisticated view than the IEP suggests.

Comment: I think the majority of philosophers do reject God, and IEP is just saying that the majority of theist philosophers think that He exists in time. As for your suggestion "it places limits on what is defined as limitless," SEP discusses this [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/eternity/#ArguDiviPerf).